# Spacebars.compile is undefined

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to manually compile some templates (to send as emails) on the server-side. However, Spacebars.compile is not defined. When I print the Spacebars object on the console, I get the following:

```
 { include: [Function],
   mustacheImpl: [Function],
   mustache: [Function],
   attrMustache: [Function],
   dataMustache: [Function],
   makeRaw: [Function],
   call: [Function],
   kw: [Function],
   SafeString: [Function],
   dot: [Function],
   TemplateWith: [Function],
   With: [Function] }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please note that I have tried including the spacebars-compile package manually, but no show.

**EDIT: Code sample**

```
function renderTemplate (template, data) {
    var compiled = Spacebars.compile(template, data);
    var render = new Function("return " + compiled)();

    var tpl = UI.Component.extend({
        kind: "dynamicTemplate",
        render: render
    });

    return tpl;
};
```

I get #<Object>.compile is undefined

Comment: Can you provide a small complete code sample that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Right now, there isn't an easy API for this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/T5tLyezaw7E

Answer (score 0):

[This answer is known to be valid for Meteor version 1.1.0.2]

First you need to add the [spacebars-compiler package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spacebars-compiler):

```
meteor add spacebars-compiler
```

Then change your invocation to use `SpacebarsCompiler.compile()`.